# How to split Excel file sheet-wise and particular sheet need to show in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

I'm creating an ASP.Net application. I need to split Excel file as sheet-wise methods (as both random wise sheet and order wise in same file). Please refer the image in that Excel file (name `Sample`) have 3 sheets so admin going to split 1. address & team name sheets and 2. mobile no alone.

How can I do that?

And also I want show the sheet (one at a time) in ASP.NET form. Please let me know how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code to get the sheet names and finally add them to any control e.g. TreeView control.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method retrieves the excel sheet names from 
/// an excel workbook.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="excelFile">The excel file.</param>
/// <returns>String[]</returns>
private String[] GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFile)
{
    OleDbConnection objConn = null;
    System.Data.DataTable dt = null;

    try
    {
        // Connection String. Change the excel file to the file you
        // will search.
        String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
          "Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        // Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.
        objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        // Open connection with the database.
        objConn.Open();
        // Get the data table containg the schema guid.
        dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        if(dt == null)
        {
           return null;
        }

        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;

        // Add the sheet name to the string array.
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
           excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
           i++;
        }

        // Loop through all of the sheets if you want too...
        for(int j=0; j < excelSheets.Length; j++)
        {
            // Query each excel sheet.
        }

        return excelSheets;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       return null;
   }
   finally
   {
      // Clean up.
      if(objConn != null)
      {
          objConn.Close();
          objConn.Dispose();
      }
      if(dt != null)
      {
          dt.Dispose();
      }
   }
}
```

Extracted from [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/getsheetnames.aspx) on the CodeProject.

Comment: thanks for reply. am not talking about treeview creation. i need suggestion for sheet splitting and excel sheet viewer in asp

Comment: @soundy, you question is incomplete i can't understand what is meant by splitting. Can you elaborate it in detail.

Comment: oh ok, imagine every node have checkbox control so i checked 'address' sheet split and assigned to particular user . so that particular user get excel file with assigned 'address' sheet only . that wat i mean split.